# JAVA SPRING: query did not return a unique result:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

```java
public interface CriterionRepo extends JpaRepository<Criterion, Long> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT c.cWeight FROM Mark m, Vector v, Alternative a, Criterion c WHERE a.idAlt=v.alternative.idAlt AND v.mark.idMark=m.idMark AND m.criterion.idCrit=c.idCrit AND a.idAlt = :id_alt")
    List<String> findCWeight(@Param("id_alt") Long id_alt);

}
```

I need to return more than 1 result but when executing the queries it gives this error:

> javax.persistence.NonUniqueResultException: query did not return a
> unique result: 2

Comment: Try naming the method `findAllCWeight`

Comment: @Andreas, didnt work